# Crystal reports 2013 with oracle DB

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports

i wanna build a crystal report using crystal reports 2013 with oracle database.
i've created an odbc connection to connect to this db named "abc".
then from the database expert in the crystal reports i've created a new connection ,then i've click on odbc ,and i choose the "abc" .
the problem is that only the stored procedure are shown , cannot find any table from the database, only the stored procedure,
i don't know why .. Can any one help me please .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the connection , go to properties and find the options. Most likely tables are not selected to be shown in the tree